# Capistrano deploy:update fails, but setup and check work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm a newbie, so apologies if this is a silly question, but can anyone help me decipher this deploy error? I've finally managed to get 'cap deploy:setup' and 'cap deploy:check' to run without errors. Now, I'm stuck at 'cap deploy:update'. Judging from the error output, it looks like there's a problem with my deploy file, but I have no idea what the problem might be. The shell output and deploy file are below. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Some background: I'm deploying to a friend's server which is running passenger. We're using ruby 1.9.2-p290, rails 3.1.3, capistrano 2.11.2, and MacOS 10.6.

Here's a sample of the deploy error output:

```
my-MacBook-Pro:projectfolder myuser$ cap deploy:update
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/arbiterapi.git master"
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/releases/20120330191423; true"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'rm -rf /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/releases/20120330191423; true'
    command finished in 663ms
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:107:in ``': No such file or directory - git ls-remote ssh://git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git master (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:107:in `block in run_locally'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:106:in `run_locally'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:44:in `block (3 levels) in load'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:96:in `with_env'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/capistrano-2.11.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/git.rb:227:in `query_revision'
... etc.
```

The rest of the error output points to the capistrano folder as well. The output seems too long to include in its entirety. But I can provide the rest if it might help!

Here's the deploy file:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.

set :application, "Project"

set :scm, "git"
set :repository,  "ssh://git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git"
set :user, "deploy"

#set :rvm_bin_path, "/usr/local/rvm/bin"
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-1.9.2-p290@project"
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = false

set :branch, "master"

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :deploy_to, "/usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/"

set :use_sudo, false

set :domain, 'project.example.ca'

role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is the line

```
No such file or directory - git ls-remote ssh://git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git master (Errno::ENOENT)
```

So it is failing at checkout out the repository. Why do you have the ssh prefix? When specifying a user (`git@`), you shouldn't have a protocol as well - the repository should just be set to

```
git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git
```

or whatever the actual URL is for git repository for the project.

FYI - neither `deploy:setup` nor `deploy:check` actually checkout the code, which is why those two work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed the ssh prefix but I get the same 'No such file or directory' error:  No such file or directory - git ls-remote git@appsrv-04.nullpointer.ca/usr/local/git_root/arbiterapi.git master (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: Is `git@appsrv-04.nullpointer.ca/usr/local/git_root/arbiterapi.git` the correct URL for your repository? If so, then your server probably doesn't have access to the repository. Assuming that you can push/pull from your own local machine, try setting `ssh_options[:forward_agent]` to true instead

Comment: Alternatively, it is possible that the `git ls-remote` is a red herring, and the actual problem is the directory /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/ does not exist. (Although I don't think it likely)

Comment: Aha. Found the problem. I had installed and un-installed macports recently. Somehow my PATH variable got messed up and git was out of commission. Now that git is working again I have a totally different set of errors that I will post separately (but link to here). Thanks for your help though!